# Why do we care about the order of a pole or zero

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

If $f(z)$ is either zero or has a singularity at a point $c$, and if the function $g(z)=(z-c)^nf(z)$ is defined and nonzero at $z=c$, then $f$ has a pole or zero of order $n$ at $c$. To me, this is an interesting classification, but as someone without any education in complex analysis (but looking to learn more), I don’t intuitively understand why this classification is important. The only place I’ve ever seen the order of a pole or zero mentioned is in the Weierstrass Factorisation Theorem, but since I’ve neither seen the proof nor really understood the theorem I don’t see the purpose of the $z^m$ term, where $m$ is the order of the zero at zero - a most confusing statement by Wikipedia.

What does the order of these points tell us about the behaviour of the function such that the classification became necessary? Why did mathematicians bother to distinguish between simple poles and zeros versus non-simple ones?

Clearly it’s not a trivial definition since it shows up in some theorems, and guessing from its place in a factorisation theorem I might guess they’re sometimes relevant in the same way that multiplicity is sometimes relevant - but I don’t know and can’t seem to find out.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, whenever we face a collection of objects, we want to *classify* them into disjoint classes of somewhat equivalent objects, knowing that equivalent objects can often be treated by equivalent approaches. For example, vector spaces (over a given field) are "equivalent" (aka. isomorphic) if they have the same dimension, thus making *dimension* a very useful classifier of vector spaces. One of the particularly interesting aspects of the classifier "order of pole" is that some singularities turn out to *not* be poles, i.e., we cannot discuss them away by multiplying with *any* power of $(z-c)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you refer here to essential singularities, right?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I appreciate for motivation for classification in general, but specifically I'd like to know what the practical difference would be between, say, a pole of order 2 vs a pole of order 3 in the analysis of a certain function

Comment: An answer might list a bunch of theorems of complex analysis where order of a pole/zero arises, but fundamentally, orders of zeros and poles let us know when dividing/multiplying by functions will give us nice limits. Knowing the order of the zero of $\cos(2z)-1$ at $0$ lets us know that $(\cos(2z)-1)/(z^2)$ will have a nice limit at $0$ instead of the division by zero being an actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps an analogy with real numbers may help. Define two
positive real numbers are commeasurable if they have a
[greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). This is an equivalence
relation on positive real numbers. Another way to define
this relation is the two real numbers are equivalent if their quotient is a positive rational number. Every
positive rational number can be uniquely factored into
positive or negative powers of prime numbers.

In the analogy with functions, the prime factors of a
rational number in the numerator correspond to function zeros and the factors in the denominator correspond to
function poles. Rational functions are relatively simple
to analyze in analogy with rational numbers. Given an
analytic function, the zeros and poles with multiplicity
combine to form a rational function. Divide the analytic
function by this rational function and the quotient has
no zeros or poles although it may still have essential singularities. This simplifies the analysis of the given
function.